# Usage of "For" before "the first time"?

Tags: difference

Sometimes when I read I notice that some authors say **"the first time"** while others say **"for the first time"**. Of course mostly in different situations but is there a difference? What does the preposition change?

1. I have done it the first time in my life.
2. I have done it for the first time in my life.

Or

1. That's the first time I've heard this song.
2. For the first time in my life I have heard this song.

Or

1. It will be the first time when I am going there.
2. It will be for the first time when I am going there.

Edit: The sentences (examples) aren't from books.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use the present perfect with a time phrase that excludes the present, which *the first time* does, unlike *for the first time*.

"The first time" requires the past tense.

> I drove a car the first time at age 16.
>
> I drove a car for the first time at age 16.
>
> WooHoo! I have driven a car for the first time!
>
> WooHoo! I have driven a car the first time! <sup>ungrammatical</sup>

P.S.  **the first time** refers to the first *of several* or of many, whereas **for the first time** refers to the first  *as first*, as something *new*.

> The first time I read that poem, it made little sense to me, but after rereading it several times, it began to make sense to me.
>
> I had never understood the poem, but after my strange experience in the noonday sun, it made sense to me for the first time.
>
> For the first time, I understand what you were going through.
>
> The first time, I understand what you were going through. <sup>ungrammatical</sup>

Comment: So, **"the first time"** can only be used in the past tense? But **"for the first time"** can be used in the past, the present, and the future?

Comment: **for the first time** is completely free-ranging time-wise.  **The first time**, *when it refers to an incident in the past*,   is incompatible with the present perfect.  But you can use **the first time** to mean **for the first time** with the future:  *The first time we visit, it will seem rather empty, because everyone will be away for the holiday. When we visit for the first time, it will seem rather empty*.

Comment: However, context can "coerce" the sentence into a statement about the speaker's deictic Present. *That is the first time I have ever driven a sports car. Thanks for letting me take a spin!*

Comment: Aha, so this way perfect makes sense. But not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

This question has confused me for a long time. In my opinion (I am not a native speaker of English):

**the first time** can be used as conjunction, while **for the first time** can only be used as adverse:

> The first time *I saw him*, he was wearing a black coat.
>
> For the first time I *saw* him wearing a black coat.

Also, **the first time** emphasizes "time point", while **for the first time** emphasizes "time line" (from past to the time the incidence happened). When we put "for the first time" inside a "when clause", it enphasizes "time point" as well, for example:

> The first I saw him, he was wearing a black coat. (time point)
>
> For the first time, I saw him wearing a black coat. (time line)
>
> When I saw him for the first time, he was wearing a black coat. (time point again)